# Name request is not defined

Tags: python, bottle

Im trying to access request object in my html but unble to access it..How can I pass the request object to my HTML

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<form action="/start" method="post">
   <span>Username:</span>
   <input type="text" name="username">
   <span>Password:</span>
   {{ request.url }}
   <input type="password" name="password">
   <input type="submit" value="Sign in">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

test.py

```
from bottle import route, run, template, redirect

@route('/hello')
def hello():
    return template('login')
run(host='localhost', port=8082, debug=True)
```

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to just pass `request` into the template like this:

```
from bottle import route, run, template, redirect
import bottle

@route('/hello')
def hello():
    return template('login', request=bottle.request)
```